# Can Android device send emergency message to 911 without SIM card?

Tags: sms, sim-card, emergency-calls

I already know that Android devices can call 911 without a SIM card (ref: [Can an Android phone with no SIM card make an emergency call?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/154651/44325)), but can they can send a message to 911 without a SIM card?

Answer (score 4):

You can call 911 on any cellphone with or without a SIM card. You may not be able to send 911 a text, a feature my county has available. To be honest, whenever I have texted 911 they text back with "Are you in a safe enough place to call 911?"....Without a SIM card I don't see that even being a possibility unfortunately. I know you can make a 911 phone call sans SIM card though.

Verified with FCC - you cannot text 911 without a working SIM card in the cellphone you are calling from.

Comment: Thanks very much for help , it is rellay useful, thanks again!

Comment: Oh no problem at all. I'm relatively new to this community so I'm still learning the ins and outs and how to be a good steward of the information contained within!